# Binding site address to port 80 in IIS breaks MAC Authentication

Tags: iis, viewstate

We have a website hosted in IIS which works when no bindings are present.

However, when we bind our domain name to port 80 we start getting this error:

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by
a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration
specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm.
AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

We have set a specfic machineKey so I'm confused as to why this is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please tell me your application is hostede by a Web Farm or cluster? Is this application a asp.net web form application? What is  your IIS version? Which mode you have used in  your application pool? the integrated or classic mode?

Comment: "when no bindings are present" is impossible, as any IIS site has at least one site binding.